# Accessing end event in PDFCrowd's saveToFile Method in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation

I'm using Node and attempting to *know* when my PDF has created by accessing the `end` event within the `saveToFile` method.  I've come up with the following, yet this doesn't actually do anything -- no PDF is generated:-

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
client.convertHtml(html, {
            pdf: function(rstream) {
                rstream.on('end', function() {
                    pdf.saveToFile(path);
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        }, a4);
});
```

I can see within the library the end method:-

```
var saveToFile = function(fname) {
    return {
        pdf: function(rstream) { 
            var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(fname);
            rstream.pipe(wstream);
        },
        error: function(errMessage, statusCode) { console.log("ERROR: " + errMessage); },
        end: function() {},
    };
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get this all to hang together.  I currently have a bluebird `Promise` wrapped around the function and the idea was to resolve the Promise on a successful end event and then move on:-

```
_generatePdf(stuffs).then(function() {
console.log('all done here');
});
```

I imagine this is all very simple -- help appreciated!

Will happily update question with more information if needed.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the end with the following code.  As hassansin hinted I wasn't picking up the data from the `rstream`:-

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var client = new pdf.Pdfcrowd(username, key);
        var data = [];
        client.convertHtml(html, {
            pdf: function(rstream) {
                rstream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    data.push(chunk);
                });

                rstream.on('end', function() {
                    var buffer = new Buffer(data.reduce(function(prev, current) {
                        return prev.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(current));
                    }, []));

                    fs.writeFile(fpath, buffer, 'binary', function onComplete(err){
                        if(err){
                            throw err;
                        }
                        resolve();
                    });
                });
            }
        }, a4);
    });
```

Hopefully this will help someone else out there having the same problems :)

Comment: You can just use `buffer = Buffer.concat(data)`. Also piping would be faster for large files.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the default function that handles writing to a file. Inside your new function you are not reading any data from the `rstream`, that's why no `end` event is emitted. Try like this:

```
 pdf: function(rstream) { 
        rstream.on('end', function() {
                pdf.saveToFile(path);
                resolve();
            });
        var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        rstream.pipe(wstream)
    },
```